# Cant run flutter project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

I have downloaded a reminder flutter project and opened it in android studio and made the changes required to run it but there is an error cant solve in app/gradle.build i have upgraded flutter to the latest version and so as android studio

the gradle.build file that has an error

```
   def localProperties = new Properties()
  def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
   if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
     localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
      localProperties.load(reader)
   }
  }

 def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
 if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
   }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
  if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
      flutterVersionCode = '1'
  }

 def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
 if (flutterVersionName == null) {
   flutterVersionName = '1.0'
  }
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

  android {
     compileSdkVersion 27

     lintOptions {
       disable 'InvalidPackage'
   }

     defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
 (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "me.tuannguyen.fluttertodo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
 }

 flutter {
source '../..'
 }

dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'
 }
```

the error here i think

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

and the error that shows to me

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 in debug mode...
 Initializing gradle...
 Resolving dependencies...
 * Error running Gradle:
 ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\tuannguyendotme-flutter_todo- 
 6261e20\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\tuannguyendotme-flutter_todo- 
6261e20\android\app\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 > ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
 log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\tuannguyendotme-flutter_todo- 
 6261e20\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

  Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Gradle.build

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
 }
   }

  allprojects {
   repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  }

 rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
 subprojects {
  project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
 }
  subprojects {
  project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
 #Wed Sep 26 21:25:02 ICT 2018
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Add your `gradle.properties` file here.

Comment: Did you make changes there? Because seems like some configuration is missing there.

Comment: @GensaGames didnt change or add anything there

Comment: @GensaGames there is just this line `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M`

Comment: your config file under `gradle/wrapper` folders name might be next `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: @GensaGames i have added the Top-level gradle build file and the gradle-wrapper.properties up

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issue with your language and navigation to the source/project files. I think building scripts just cannot load all the resources.

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\tuannguyendotme-flutter_todo- 
6261e20\android\app\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 > ASCII
```

Start your investigation with the next line. As you can see **6261e20** should be some name, but omitted because of decoding.

```
Build file 'C:\Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\tuannguyendotme-flutter_todo- 
6261e20\android\app\build.gradle' line: 23
```